# Calling Webservice from NIFI with proxy

Tags: web-services, curl, apache-nifi

I need to configure a NIFI flow that invokes a webservice. The curl command works fine from the cmd line of my nifi host

```
curl -U <user>:<password> -x <ip>:8080 -H 'SOAPACTION:"http://method"'-X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d  @req.xml https://url -o result2.xml
```

Im trying to configure NIFI InvokeHTTP processor to make the call from within a nifi flow with following settings.

```
HTTP Method:POST
Remote URL: https://url
Proxy Host: <ip>
Proxy Port: 8080
Proxy Username: <user>
Proxy Password: <password>
SOAPAction: method (Dynamic Properties)
```

But it keeps running in the Failure queue.

[image]

how do i configure my InvokeHTTP according to the curl command which works ok?

Comment: could you please edit the question and provide a full stacktrace for this error from `nifi/logs/nifi-app.log` file.

Answer (score 1):

We updated the version of the InvokeHTTP component from 1.3.0 to the newest